# Why will this error be ignored?

Tags: javascript, exception

I am reading Eloquent JavaScript and there is a part of the code that I do not understand.

```
for (;;) {
    try {
        var dir = promtDirection(" Where ?"); // ← typo !
        console.log(" You chose ", dir);
        break;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(" Not a valid direction . Try again .");
    }
}
```

The book says:

> But we misspelled promptDirection , which will result in an “undefined
>   variable” error. Because the catch block completely ignores its
>   exception value ( e ), assuming it knows what the problem is, it
>   wrongly treats the variable error as indicating bad input.

But if it is blanket-catching the exceptions, shouldn't it just catch the error generated by the typo print the line?

Comment: The point of try catch is to make it so your program does not terminate when errors occur. You catch the error so you can deal with it and allow your program to move on. The passage is saying that you should do further checking in the catch (ie actually check the error message), as this catch just assumes the wrong answer was supplied when in fact its a coding mistake that caused the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if it is blanket-catching the exceptions, shouldn't it just catch the error generated by the typo

Yes.

At which point it will claim that the direction was invalid, which isn't the correct error.

> and terminate?

No, it will go to the next iteration of the for loop (at which point it will hit the same error, repeat ad infinitum).

Comment: *"No, it will go to the next iteration of the for loop."* And keep going forever...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that the catch block assumes that the error will be related to user input. But it's not, and since the real error (passed as e) is never displayed the developer will be misguided searching it. To be "eloquent" your code should use the e variable to display a more useful message.